# Is there a name for this function?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, terminology

this should be simple

A polynomial could be defined as 
\begin{equation}
P_n (x) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i x^{i-1}
\end{equation}

Would the infinite-dimensional version of that
\begin{equation}
F_l (x) = \int_{0}^{l} a(y) x^y dy
\end{equation}
already have some name that everybody else than me already knows?

Comment: Your function is not really a generalization of a polynomial since the exponent is not a natural number; a better generalization might be $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ which is the very-well known and important concept of power series.

Comment: Well it is not polynomial as it is not a polynomial that's true. But I think there is certain similarity.

Comment: Indeed; I just wanted to point out another, maybe more "in the spirit of polynomials" possible generalization.

Comment: You may have a look at the Mellin transform and its inverse: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_transform

Answer (score 3):

With the substitution $x=e^{i\omega}$ is is known as Fourier-transform.

Comment: Or the substitution $x = e^{-s}$, with $l = \infty$ gives the Laplace transform...

Comment: Yes, like the polynomial would be discrete Fourier transfom or spectral decomposition.